# How do I create a different variable name inside a loop?

Tags: python, loops, variables, csv

## Here is the code to start with.

Ignoring all the CSV jazz if you want, the important part is the loop.

```
import csv

Teacher_Array = []

class Teacher:

    def __init__ (self, login, password, name, room, booked):
        self.password = password
        self.name = name
        self.login = login
        self.booked = booked
        self.room = room


with open('file.csv') as f:

    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        if len(row) < 10 and len(row) > 2:
```

## Ok.

The cvs stuff is a little besides the point, the key info is the loop, how do I create different variable names each time?

At this point I want to create teacher objects say,

MrDongle = Teacher(row[0], row[1], row[3], etc)

However I can't make a new name in the loop! Help please.

Much love, some dumb teenager.

Comment: Maybe you would like to put them into a `dict`? `some_dict['MrDongle'] = Teacher(...)`

Comment: Creating a bunch of variable names might not be the best solution.  You could just collect the object instances in a list.  Depending on what you intend to do with the results, this might be prefered to storing a dictionary, as suggested before.

Answer (score 0):

Well, just make a name a key in a dictionary:

```
teachers = {}
....
teachers['MrDongle'] = Teacher(row[0], row[1], row[3], etc)
```

**EDIT**
Actually, you can generate a name:

```
exec('{} = Teacher(...)'.format('MrDongle', ...)
```

but this is unscalable and improper solution.